# Matching two columns in one data frame against two columns in another, independently of the order

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Given two data frames as example:

```
df1 = data.frame(V1 = c('JOHN', 'BRIAN','KATE', 'ERIC', 'CURT', 'ZACH'), V2 = c('ABIGAIL', 'ANDY', 'GEORGE', 'JOHN', 'MARY', 'FRANKLIN'), V3 = seq(1,6,1), V4 = seq(1,6,1))
df2 = data.frame(V1 = c('ABIGAIL', 'BRIAN','KATE', 'ERIC'), V2 = c('JOHN', 'ANDY', 'MARTIN', 'ANDREW'))

df1
V1       V2 V3 V4
JOHN  ABIGAIL  1  1
BRIAN     ANDY  2  2
KATE   GEORGE  3  3
ERIC     JOHN  4  4
CURT     MARY  5  5
ZACH FRANKLIN  6  6

df2
V1     V2 
ABIGAIL   JOHN
BRIAN   ANDY
KATE MARTIN
ERIC ANDREW
```

How can I create a new `df3` containing the rows that match between columns `V1`and `V2` in `df1`and `df2`. The challenge is that I want this match independently of the order.

So that `df3`would in the example look like:

```
  df3
  V1   V2 V3 V4
  ABIGAIL JOHN 1 1
  BRIAN ANDY  2  2
```

I have tried using match() and the %in% operator without any luck.

I am looking for a solution applicable a data frame with several thousand rows.

#### EDIT

Both answers gave a working solution to my question. It turns out I missed something to make it applicable to my own data. Instead given the data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(V1 = c('JOHN', 'BRIAN','KATE', 'ERIC', 'CURT', 'ZACH'), V2 = c('ABIGAIL', 'ANDY', 'GEORGE', 'JOHN', 'MARY', 'FRANKLIN'), V3 = seq(1,6,1), V4 = seq(1,6,1))
df2 = data.frame(V1 = c('ABIGAIL', 'BRIAN','KATE', 'BRIAN', 'ERIC'), V2 = c('JOHN', 'ANDY', 'MARTIN', 'ANDY', 'ANDREW'))
```

Now I also want to extract the rows even if the match between them are not in the same row. `df3`would then look like:

```
df3
V1   V2 V3 V4
ABIGAIL JOHN 1 1
BRIAN ANDY  2  2
BRIAN ANDY  2  2
```

Basically I want the values in `V3` and `V4` from `df1` for every interactions between the names in `V1`and `V2`independently of the order.

Comment: Looks like you need `inner_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: @akrun I missed some important info that I have added know. I don't think I can use inner_join in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make ID by sorting the columns V1 and V2 rowwise using *pmin* and *pmax*, so that `"A" "B"` and `"B" "A"` will have same ID as `"A_B"`. Then use *merge* by ID:

```
df1$ID <- paste(pmin(as.character(df1$V1), as.character(df1$V2)),
                pmax(as.character(df1$V1), as.character(df1$V2)), sep = "_")

df2$ID <- paste(pmin(as.character(df2$V1), as.character(df2$V2)),
                pmax(as.character(df2$V1), as.character(df2$V2)), sep = "_")

merge(df1, df2[, "ID", drop = FALSE], by = "ID")

#             ID    V1      V2 V3 V4
# 1 ABIGAIL_JOHN  JOHN ABIGAIL  1  1
# 2   ANDY_BRIAN BRIAN    ANDY  2  2
# 3   ANDY_BRIAN BRIAN    ANDY  2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(combinat)
df1[apply(df1[,1:2], 1, paste, collapse = ' ') %in%
    apply(df2[,1:2], 1, function(x) sapply(permn(x), paste, collapse = ' '))
    ,]
```

Using `sqldf` as below is faster, but doesn't work as easily for > 2 variables since all possibilities must be listed in the join condition.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('
select  df1.*
from    df1
        inner join df2
            on  (df1.V1 = df2.V1 and df1.V2 = df2.V2)
                or (df1.V1 = df2.V2 and df1.V2 = df2.V1)
')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a package; just test for both ways with:

```
## Make a frame with combined in both ways
df1o = data.frame(V12 =paste(df1$V1,df1$V2, sep="-"), V21= paste(df1$V2,df1$V1, sep="-"))
## Make a frame with the second combination
df2o = data.frame(P =paste(df2$V1,df2$V2, sep="-") )
## Compare the combinations in both ways and select those that match in a new df
df3 = df1[which(df1o$V12 %in% df2o$P | df1o$V21 %in% df2o$P),]
df3
```

Results in

```
> df3
     V1      V2 V3 V4
1  JOHN ABIGAIL  1  1
2 BRIAN    ANDY  2  2Z
```